# Constant reference_wrapper

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, reference-wrapper

In the following code, the aim is to have a `reference_wrapper<int> b` such that when `a` changes, `b` also changes however, the opposite should not be allowed that is, `a` should not change when `b` changes. I tried two ways: Lines 7 and 8. Line 7 caused compiler to complain that it cannot convert from `int` to `const int` while line 8 compiled without problem but the result was not what I wanted (`a` changed when `b` changed). Any idea?

```
1.  #include <iostream>
2.  #include <functional>
3.  using namespace std;
4.  
5.  int main() {
6.      int a = 1;
7.      //reference_wrapper<const int> b = ref(a);
8.      //const reference_wrapper<int> b = ref(a);
9.  return 0;
10. }
```

Comment: You can always get rid of `ref` `std::reference_wrapper<const int> b{a};`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A constant reference could be retrieved by `cref`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    reference_wrapper<const int> b = cref(a);
    return 0;
}
```